# Dynamically add option to attribute

Tags: attributes

I've been searching for a way to dynamically add more fields to a attribute on a product in backend.

I believe the closest thing I've come to, is to make a custom function with `addAttributeOption` - is that correct?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the product attributes in place, and you want to add lot of options to these attributes it becomes time consuming and hectic task. If you have only few attribute options to add, it’s easy to go to backend and add manually. But if you have many attribute options, more than 10 options for many attributes, it’s very tiresome and feels like data entry job. Magento is not built to do stuff manually, so here I will provide you the code snippet which will push all the attribute options to their respective attribute.

Create a file in the root of your Magento installation and copy this code there. I generally name it **test.php**

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

//Change this....
$aColors = array('PINK','BLACK','BLUE','BROWN','GOLD','GRAY','GREEN','MULTI','NEUTRALS/CREAM/WHITE','ORANGE','PURPLE','RED','RUST','TAUPE','YELLOW');
$attrCode = 'color'; //this should be there already
//........

$aColors = array_map('utf8_encode',$aColors); //If you're using special characters
$iProductEntityTypeId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
$aOption = array();
$aOption['attribute_id'] = $installer->getAttributeId($iProductEntityTypeId, $attrCode);

for($iCount=0;$iCount<sizeof($aColors);$iCount++){
   $aOption['value']['option'.$iCount][0] = $aColors[$iCount];
}
$installer->addAttributeOption($aOption);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Thanks, will have a test set up today and see how it works out :-)